# Setter not working when convert JSON to object class in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, object, casting, getter-setter

In typescript, I want to convert JSON data to object class but every setter not running.

I have class CreateMeetingDto:

```
export class CreateMeetingDto  {
    private _meetingID : string;
    private _name : string;

    get meetingID(): string {
        return this._meetingID;
    }

    set meetingID(value: string) {
        this._meetingID = encodeURIComponent(value);
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value: string) {
        this._name = encodeURIComponent(value);
    }

}
```

And this is code convert JSON to object class:

```
const jsonData = {
    "meetingID": "1234",
    "name": "Test Meeting"
};
const createMeetingDto = jsonData as CreateMeetingDto;
console.log(createMeetingDto.name); 
// it is "Test Meeting" not "Test%20Meeting" => function in setter not working
```

How to run setter when convert json data to object class in typescript?

Comment: `jsonData as CreateMeetingDto` This is a type cast. It does not create an instance of the class. Therefor the compiler thinks that `createMeetingDto` is an instance of `CreateMeetingDto` but it is really not, just just casted the type. You need to create an actual instance (with `new`) for the setters to work

Comment: Thanks you, I think I need constructor get json data and map this to fields.